# Troubleshooting OpenID Connect authentication in Tableau 9

Tags: tableau-api, openid-connect

I noticed that with e.g. SAML and Kerberos there's a section specifically for troubleshooting in the online help (http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/saml_trouble.htm). But what about troubleshooting OpenID Connect? So far, i've tried with two different OpenID Providers (MITREid Connect and Keycloak), with one of them i'm getting an error message "Sign in failed" and with the other one i get "User could not be found".

I've triple checked that the user names in the OpenID Providers are the same with the user names in Tableau. I'm also using local authentication in Tableau, instead of AD. And i've reset the openid subs when switching between OpenID Providers.

I enabled debug logging for wgserver and vizportal but couldn't get any clear reason as to why the signing fails or the user is not found (altough i can see that it processes the login).

Any ideas where i could look next?

Also, it would be helpful to understand what kind of OpenID configuration Tableau is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Probably already resolved so it's so old but for anybody having this issue at this point I would recommend making sure all the configuration for openID is correct per this doc:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v9.3/server/en-us/openid_auth_server_config.htm (9.3 Doc, change for which version you are in)

and if there issues, check this doc:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v9.3/server/en-us/openid_auth_troubleshooting.htm

Good luck!